# PHP usort to sort election pcts

Tags: php, usort

Looked through several questions on this but couldn't seem to get usort to do anything. I'd like to order "pct" from highest percentage to lowest percentage. Below is my code...

```
    <?
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->pct - $b->pct;
});
curl_close($ch);
foreach ($data->races as $slug => $race) {
    $p = $race->pctCount;
    $pRetty = prettyNum($p);
    $multiball = ($race->pos > 1) ? '<a class="multiRace"><em>Top '.$race->pos.' advance</em></a>' : false;
    echo '<div class="race"><h3>'.$race->race.'</h3>'.$multiball.'<table class="'.$slug.' race">';
    if ($race->pctCount != 0) { echo '<div class="pace" data-pct="'.round($p,3).'"><a class="progbar"></a>'.$pRetty.' counted</div>'; }
    foreach ($race->candidates as $cand) {
            echo '<tr class="cand '.$cand->party.'"><td class="bar"><a class="statsBar"></a></td><td>'.$cand->name.' ('.$cand->party.')'.'</td><td class="results">'.prettyNum($cand->pct).'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table></div>';
}

function prettyNum($num) {
    return (round($num,3)*100).'%';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your PHP Version?

Answer (score 0):

In your `usort` callback you are returning a subtraction result, not a comparison. You have do do something like this:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->pct < $b-pct;    // or any other comparing like equals, greater, etc.
});
```